# Can any one explain about counter with simple example?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I am new for Jmeter, any one please explain about counter with simple example and also please explain to set the test environment.

1. I have added a new Thread group and then add a counter(start=1, increment=1, Maximum= 5, Number of format=0, Reference name=null, and checked the Track counter check box).
2. Added a Http Request and a Listener.

Answer (score 2):

In simple words,

Counter functionality is exactly similar to its name.

it's task is to create a counter initialized to a value and then iterate over it till a max value.

You can access it like a variable `${mycounter}`

**Usage:**
It can be used in scenarios where sequential iteration over a range is required.

simplest example : my users have names like user1, user2......user10

```
I can use a counter named mycounter
start : 1 
end : 10
increment : 1
```

Use it in req like user${mycounter}

Note : Press ctrl + h after selecting counter in jmeter for help.